# How to take screenshot using command in Selenium IDE [New Version]

Tags: selenium-ide

This question was already asked but the version of Selenium IDE is changed now.

Previously there was command but screenshot  command is removed in new Selenium IDE.

Please help me if anyone knows any workaround.

Comment: I have the same issue. Older tutorials show commands that are not listed in the current chrome version.